# Azure App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

If I select an app service plan that allows scaling up to 10 instances, will I be charged the price stated for that plan or will I be charged 10 * [the Price of the plan]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure App Service plans support a variety of pricing models, thus it depends on the type of plan.

Generally, the "idea" of Azure App Service plans is that you pay for a specific set of resources (CPU, memory, disk etc.) that are shared among all of your applications/ instances. That means you generally pay a "flat fee" for the plan and can run as many apps as you like, as long as the resources can support it - and you don't exceed any limits or quotas. If you run too many apps however, performance as a whole will degrade, due to shared resources getting exhausted.

[Here is a good documentation explaining the concepts behind App Service plans.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans)

Things get more complicated when looking at the more expensive plans. There are models where your applications are hosted on dedicated virtual machines. This *may* be consideres as "paying for a certain number of instances", but it depends on your opinion of what the term "instance" means.